# Running Firestore Emulators before integration tests start

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

I am trying to use Firestore emulators with my Spring Boot Integration tests. I can start the emulator manually in a different terminal session, but I want to start the emulator automatically before my integration tests start as I can't always start the emulator manually, for example in my CI Pipeline. I have tried to make a gradle task, but this runs synchronously so the integration tests don't start until I finish that task which would obviously stop the emulator. Is there any way of making the gradle task run asynchronously and in parallel as my integrationTest task?

Answer (score 1):

Little late to the party but...
You can run the test from the same command as starting the emulator eg.

```
firebase emulators:exec --only firestore "./gradlew test"
```